# How can I require postgres login to require a password

Tags: postgresql

```
$ psql --password --username=postgres template1
Password for user postgres:
psql (9.4.7)
Type "help" for help.

template1=#
```

I am able to log in no matter what I type for the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a few different things going on, and it's hard to know which without knowing more about your configuration.

Specifically, you should look at your pg_hba.conf file for that database. The most likely situation is that you have a line that looks something like:

```
local   all       postgres                         trust
```

That line will allow: anyone who has command-line access to the server (`local`) to log into any database (`all`) as the postgres user (`postgres`) without password authentication (`trust`).

If you have a line like that, that's your problem. You can change `trust` to `md5` (or something else -- see [this documentation page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for more options), and that will start enforcing passwords for local database access.

If you don't see a line like that, there's something else going on.